# Does liquid count as ground?

Tags: dnd-4e, spells

Is there any consensus as to whether a Tenser's Floating Disk floats over water?

[What counts as ground?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4188/what-counts-as-ground-for-tensers-floating-disk) asks a related question, but the water thing isn't asked nor answered there.

So, would you have it float above the water's surface, or above the ground below the water/liquid?

Comment: Can the explicit question of water be added to the original question, and the answer revisited?

Comment: @Soulrift That's not how we do thing 'round here. Changing a question to make it cover a newly-asked one is inappropriate. If it is *already* covered by that question enough to justify marking this as duplicate, it is contradictory to say that it needs to be *edited* before it can cover this same question. It's either a duplicate and the other doesn't need changing, or this is a new non-duplicate and the other doesn't need changing.

Comment: Considering the answers to the other question are largely that there is no formal definition beyond DM fiat, the answers there are likely to be the same as those that would be found here, specifying water doesn't change them.  Soulrift's new answer over there even talks about Water explicitly though.